# How to Inherit pivot view in Odoo 13

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

How can I inherit pivot view in report.pos.order and add a field from crm.team model
Any help please? Thanks.

```
class PosOrderReportExtend(models.Model):
    _inherit = "report.pos.order"

team_id = fields.Many2one('crm.team', string='Sales Team')


<record id="report_pos_order_pivot_extend" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">report.pos.order.pivot.extend</field>
            <field name="model">report.pos.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="point_of_sale.view_report_pos_order_pivot"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                 <pivot string="Point of Sale Analysis" disable_linking="True">
                   <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_id']" position="after">
                    <field name="invoiced_target" type="measure"/>
                   </xpath>

              </pivot>
            </field> </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward, yours is correct, just need to remove these 2 lines:

```
<record id="report_pos_order_pivot_extend" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">report.pos.order.pivot.extend</field>
    <field name="model">report.pos.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="point_of_sale.view_report_pos_order_pivot"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
<!--        <pivot string="Point of Sale Analysis" disable_linking="True">-->
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_id']" position="after">
            <field name="invoiced_target" type="measure"/>
        </xpath>
<!--        </pivot>-->
    </field> 
</record>
```

Comment: I got this error : res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column report_pos_order.team_id does not exist
LINE 2: ...s_order"."order_id") AS "order_id",COUNT(DISTINCT "report_po...

Comment: the error was field `invoiced_target` desn't exist when installing the module.

Comment: you need to add invoiced_target field to report.pos.order model

Comment: should I add sql request ?

Comment: no, just add the field to the model
`class PosOrderReport(models.Model):
    _inherit = "report.pos.order"
    invoiced_target = fields.float('Target')`

Comment: , but I don't want to add new field , this field from model :  'crm.team'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227781/discussion-between-sdbot-and-k-ju).